# Displaying ArrayList to user

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I have two activities,  one is MainActivity and another one is Main2Activity.
In the Main2Activity I'm taking input from the user in TextView and storing it in ArrayList, now I want to send this ArrayList to MainActivity, where I will display it to the user.
I have used intent.
But my app is getting crashed.
Below are my two activities code 
Mainactivity

```
    package com.example.to_doapp;

   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
   import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.widget.LinearLayout;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;
   import java.io.Serializable;
   import java.util.ArrayList;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   public void onclick (View view  )
   {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
            Main2Activity.class );
        startActivity(intent);
  }

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    //Toast.makeText (this,intent.getStringExtra("task"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show() ;

    Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
     ArrayList< String> object  =  (ArrayList<String>) args.getSerializable("ARRAYLIST");
    LinearLayout lView = new LinearLayout(this);
    TextView myText= new TextView(this);
    lView.addView(myText);
    for (int i=0; i<object.size();i++){
        myText.append(object.get(i));
        myText.append("\n");
    }
    setContentView(lView);

 }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;       }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
  }
```

Main2Activity is 
        package com.example.to_doapp;

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList< String> arr = new ArrayList < String > ();
    public void BackMain ( View view )
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext() 
           ,MainActivity.class ) ;
       Bundle args = new Bundle();
        EditText editText = ( EditText) findViewById( R.id.editText3) ;
        String s = editText.getText().toString();
       arr.add ( s ) ;
       args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)arr);
        intent.putExtra("bundle",args);
       startActivity(intent);
     }

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
         fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
       });
       }

       }
```

My Logcat shows somethinng like this

> 03-21 07:55:00.407 763-826/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException
>   caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=81,
>   legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
>   03-21 07:55:58.292 29529-29529/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class:
>   com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport 03-21 07:56:01.380
>   29645-29672/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class:
>   com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport 03-21 07:56:01.577
>   29624-29624/com.example.to_doapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>       Process: com.example.to_doapp, PID: 29624
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.to_doapp/com.example.to_doapp.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.io.Serializable
>   android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object
>   reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable
>   android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object
>   reference
>           at com.example.to_doapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)  03-21
>   07:56:01.787 29645-29670/? E/WifiManager: mWifiServiceMessenger ==
>   null 03-21 07:56:03.275 29764-29764/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class:
>   com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport 03-21 07:56:03.390
>   29645-29671/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb47ac800 cert_verify_callback
>   x509_store_ctx=0x9fa343e0 arg=0x0 03-21 07:56:03.390 29645-29671/?
>   E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb47ac800 cert_verify_callback calling
>   verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_ECDSA 03-21 07:56:03.536
>   29645-29672/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xaf83da00 cert_verify_callback
>   x509_store_ctx=0x9f930460 arg=0x0 03-21 07:56:03.536 29645-29672/?
>   E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xaf83da00 cert_verify_callback calling
>   verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_ECDSA 03-21 07:56:03.584
>   29787-29787/? E/WifiManager: mWifiServiceMessenger == null 03-21
>   07:56:04.382 29787-29787/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class:
>   com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport 03-21 07:56:04.743
>   29838-29838/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class:
>   com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport 03-21 07:56:11.598
>   29645-29681/? E/Finsky: [4373] fng.a(20): Unable to build selector:
>   /storage/sdcard0/Download/marketenvs.csv: open failed: ENOENT (No such
>   file or directory) 03-21 07:56:11.772 29645-29724/? E/SQLiteLog: (283)
>   recovered 63 frames from WAL file
>   /data/data/com.android.vending/databases/phenotype.db-wal 03-21
>   07:56:55.470 763-763/? E/WifiTrafficPoller: ENABLE_TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL
>   false Token 226 03-21 07:56:55.535 763-823/? E/WifiStateMachine: 
>   ScanModeState (when=-58ms what=131167!CMD_SCREEN_STATE_CHANGED{
>   when=-58ms what=131167
>   target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler } 0 0 03-21
>   07:56:55.536 763-823/? E/WifiStateMachine:  DriverStartedState
>   (when=-58ms what=131167!CMD_SCREEN_STATE_CHANGED{ when=-58ms
>   what=131167 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
>   0 0 03-21 07:56:55.536 763-823/? E/WifiStateMachine: 
>   SupplicantStartedState (when=-59ms
>   what=131167!CMD_SCREEN_STATE_CHANGED{ when=-59ms what=131167
>   target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler } 0 0 03-21
>   07:56:55.537 763-823/? E/WifiStateMachine:  DefaultState (when=-60ms
>   what=131167!CMD_SCREEN_STATE_CHANGED{ when=-60ms what=131167
>   target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler } 0 0 03-21
>   07:56:55.547 763-823/? E/WifiStateMachine: cancelDelayedScan -> 228
>   03-21 07:56:55.547 763-823/? E/WifiStateMachine:
>   handleScreenStateChanged Exit: false 03-21 07:56:55.548 763-823/?
>   E/WifiStateMachine:  ScanModeState (when=-4ms
>   what=131154CMD_ENABLE_RSSI_POLL{ when=-4ms what=131154
>   target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler } 0 0 03-21
>   07:56:55.550 763-823/? E/WifiStateMachine:  DriverStartedState
>   (when=-6ms what=131154CMD_ENABLE_RSSI_POLL{ when=-6ms what=131154
>   target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler } 0 0 03-21
>   07:56:55.550 763-823/? E/WifiStateMachine:  SupplicantStartedState
>   (when=-6ms what=131154CMD_ENABLE_RSSI_POLL{ when=-6ms what=131154
>   target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler } 0 0 03-21
>   07:56:55.551 763-823/? E/WifiStateMachine:  DefaultState (when=-6ms
>   what=131154CMD_ENABLE_RSSI_POLL{ when=-7ms what=131154
>   target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler } 0 0 03-21
>   07:56:55.551 763-823/? E/WifiStateMachine:  ScanModeState (when=-6ms
>   what=131158 arg1=1CMD_SET_SUSPEND_OPT_ENABLED{ when=-6ms what=131158
>   arg1=1 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler } 1 0
>   03-21 07:56:55.552 763-823/? E/WifiStateMachine:  DriverStartedState
>   (when=-7ms what=131158 arg1=1CMD_SET_SUSPEND_OPT_ENABLED{ when=-7ms
>   what=131158 arg1=1
>   target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler } 1 0 03-21
>   07:56:55.574 763-823/? E/WifiStateMachine:
>   setSuspendOptimizationsNative: 4 true -want true
>   stack:setSuspendOptimizationsNative - access$16400 - processMessage -
>   processMsg 03-21 07:56:55.575 763-823/? E/WifiStateMachine:
>   setSuspendOptimizationsNative do it 4 true
>   stack:setSuspendOptimizationsNative - access$16400 - processMessage -
>   processMsg 03-21 07:56:55.585 763-823/? E/native: do suspend true
>   03-21 07:56:55.599 763-823/? E/WifiStateMachine:  ScanModeState
>   (when=-53ms what=131248M_CMD_NOTIFY_SCREEN_OFF{ when=-53ms what=131248
>   target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler } 0 0 03-21
>   07:56:55.599 763-823/? E/WifiStateMachine:  DriverStartedState
>   (when=-54ms what=131248M_CMD_NOTIFY_SCREEN_OFF{ when=-54ms what=131248
>   target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler } 0 0 03-21
>   07:56:55.600 763-823/? E/WifiStateMachine:  SupplicantStartedState
>   (when=-54ms what=131248M_CMD_NOTIFY_SCREEN_OFF{ when=-55ms what=131248
>   target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler } 0 0 03-21
>   07:56:55.601 763-823/? E/WifiStateMachine:  DefaultState (when=-55ms
>   what=131248M_CMD_NOTIFY_SCREEN_OFF{ when=-55ms what=131248
>   target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler } 0 0 03-21
>   07:56:56.504 1773-29908/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class:
>   com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport 03-21 07:56:56.635
>   763-779/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0) 03-21 07:56:56.636
>   763-779/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0) 03-21 07:56:56.638
>   763-779/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000)m, error(0),
>   index(2) 03-21 07:57:00.388 763-1406/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver
>   handle(0) 03-21 07:57:28.639 1673-13747/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM
>   release without a matched acquire!

Comment: Post your Crash/error/exception here. see your logcat for exception details.

Comment: any update ????

Comment: John Joe I Upadated  whatever you said what Still Its not working :(

Comment: @shalininegi not working mean ? same error ?

Comment: John Joe sir, the app is again crashing !!  :(

Comment: post new error please

Answer (score 0):

To pass arrayList object to another activity, use this code.

In Main2Activity

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
EditText editText = ( EditText) findViewById( R.id.editText3) ;
String s = editText.getText().toString();
arr.add (s) ;
intent.putExtra("mylist", arr);
```

In MainActivity

```
ArrayList<String> object = (ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("mylist");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because from the log:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at com.example.to_doapp.MainActivity.onCreate(**MainActivity.java:51**)

In your method `public void BackMain ( View view )`(suggest to rename the method to "backMain" according to [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)) in Main2Activity, you have `intent.putExtra("bundle",args);` where the key(or name) of the extra data which is the first argument is "bundle". However, when you get this extra data from MainActivity, you have `Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");` where the name of the bundle is "BUNDLE" which does not match "bundle" so it will return null. You need to use same name for the extra data(in this case a `Bundle`) that you want to pass through Intent from one Activity to the other.